# Get Last 5 Business days and exclude holidays list Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I created the function to get the last 5 business days. It will display the last 5th day of the month for the schedule.

I created one table that contains the holidays list. Could you please help me to modify the function. I tried the function as follows,

Following query to insert

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T_FACT_JOB_HOLIDAY_LIST WHERE HDLY_DATE = end_date)
```

**Main Query:**

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION test.Func_to_get_last_n_busi_days ( 
p_curr_date IN DATE, 
p_days_cnt  IN NUMBER) 
RETURN DATE 
IS 
  v_curr_date      DATE := Trunc(p_curr_date); 
  v_days_cnt       NUMBER := p_days_cnt; 
  v_month_end_date DATE; 
  v_sche_date      DATE; 
BEGIN 
    v_month_end_date := Last_day(v_curr_date); 

    IF v_month_end_date = v_curr_date THEN 
      v_month_end_date := Last_day(v_curr_date + 1); 
    END IF; 

    SELECT Min(last_n_days) 
    INTO   v_sche_date 
    FROM   (SELECT last_n_days 
            FROM   (SELECT ROWNUM rw, 
                           end_date - LEVEL + 1 last_n_days 
                    FROM   (SELECT Add_months(( v_month_end_date + 1 ), -1) AS 
                                   start_date, 
                                   v_month_end_date                         AS 
                                   end_date 
                            FROM   dual) 
                    WHERE  To_char(end_date - LEVEL + 1, 'DY') NOT IN 
                           ( 'SAT', 'SUN' ) 
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ( end_date - start_date ) + 1) 
            WHERE  rw <= v_days_cnt) 
    WHERE  last_n_days > v_curr_date; 

    RETURN Trunc(v_sche_date); 
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
             Raise_application_error(-20010, SQLERRM); 
END; 

/
```

Comment: You should use `To_char(end_date - LEVEL + 1, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american')` in order to be independent from current user session NLS settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can generate the list of the dates from v_month_end_date till v_curr_date like this:

```
  select v_month_end_date - level  + 1 as d
  from dual
  connect by v_month_end_date - v_curr_date >= level -1
```

then you can filter the dates on weekdays and holidays like this:

```
select  d 
from 
(
      select v_month_end_date - level  + 1 as d
      from dual
      connect by v_month_end_date - v_curr_date >= level -1
)
where To_char(d, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') NOT IN ( 'SAT', 'SUN' ) 
and NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T_FACT_JOB_HOLIDAY_LIST WHERE HDLY_DATE = d)
order by d desc
```

in the next step you filter only the required number of the bussines days and select the min date

```
select min(d)
into v_sche_date 
FROM
(
  SELECT d
  from
  (
    select rownum rn, d 
    from
    (
        select  d 
        from 
        (
              select v_month_end_date - level  + 1 as d
              from dual
              connect by v_month_end_date - v_curr_date >= level -1
        )
        where To_char(d, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') NOT IN ( 'SAT', 'SUN' ) 
        and NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T_FACT_JOB_HOLIDAY_LIST WHERE TRUNC(HDLY_DATE, 'DD') = d)
        order by d desc
    )
  )
  where 
   rn <= v_days_cnt
)
```

Comment: Still I am getting the following error. Could you pleas help to resolve it.

ORA-20010: ORA-32037: unsupported use of LEVEL in membership condition
ORA-06512: at "FUNC_GET_LAST_N_BUSI_DAY", line 40

Comment: Still getting the issue with this function. could you please share the full function.
I am looking for following scenarios to be covered.
1. Exclude Sat & Sun.
2. Exclude Holidays from the table.
3. Get min of Last 5 business days.
(ex. 1. Input date :  8/28/2017   output : 8/29/2017
2. Input Date: 8/31/2017 output: 9/25/2017)

Comment: what exactly are the issues, that you have ?

Comment: my toad got hanged when I tried to execute the function which you provided.

Comment: what values do `v_month_end_date, v_curr_date, v_days_cnt` have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152241/discussion-between-vasanth-and-schurik).

Comment: Thanks @schurik It is working good. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You tried:

```
... AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T_FACT_JOB_HOLIDAY_LIST 
                     WHERE HDLY_DATE = end_date)
```

and you should try (line 28):

```
... AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T_FACT_JOB_HOLIDAY_LIST 
                      WHERE HDLY_DATE = end_date - LEVEL + 1)
```

But maybe this function is a bit unreadable. You can also do this simple loop:

```
create or replace function get_business_day (p_curr_date in date, p_days_cnt in number ) 
    return date is

    v_date date := last_day(p_curr_date);
    i number := 0;
    v_tmp number;
begin
    while i < p_days_cnt loop
        v_date := v_date - 1;
        begin 
            select 1 into v_tmp from t_fact_job_holiday_list where hdly_date = v_date;
        exception when no_data_found then
            i := i + 1;
        end;
    end loop;
    return v_date;
end;
```

Comment: I am getting following error when I try to include it in line no 28: "ORA-20010: ORA-01788: CONNECT BY clause required in this query block"

I tired your new query as well. But it is not excluding the SAT and SUN. Also IF the day is 31st Aug 2017. It should give the next month min date of last 5 business days.

Thanks for your help. If you add this two scenarios that would be great.